# How do I insert or update data using value in table A if a value exists in one of 2 tables say, B and C?

Tags: mysql, polymorphic-associations

I've 3 tables:

```
switches     (device_id char(20), room_id char(36), ...)
sensors      (device_id char(20), room_id char(36), ...)
device_rssi  (device_addr char(16), room_id char(36), rssi, ...)
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
If addr already exists in device_rssi
then 
    update the rssi in the device_rssi table
else
    if addr exists in either switches or sensors tables
        get the room_id for that addr from whichever table it exists in
        add the rssi along with the room_id in the device_rssi table
```

(Note that the device_id is 'device_addr + 4 chars')

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT room_id
    FROM switches
    WHERE device_id like addr____
    UNION
    SELECT room_id
    FROM sensors
    WHERE device_id like addr____
    );
```

And then in my C code, I check if the query returned a room_id followed by this query:

```
INSERT INTO device_rssi
(device_addr, room_id, rssi) VALUES (addr, room_id, rssi)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE room_id = room_id, rssi = rssi;
```

First off, I'd have liked to have a 'devices' table with both switches and sensors having a foreign key reference for the device_id, room_id fields. That'd have solved my problem of "checking whether a device_addr exists in either of the tables and getting the room_id". But I'm not allowed to do that because it will add too much work for the app/web services guys. So, I've to work with what I have.

Secondly, I hate the fact that I'm querying the room_id every time I update the rssi even though room_id for a switch/sensor will rarely ever change.

And, of course, not to mention for something that is supposed to be very simple, I've come up with 2 queries where 1 has a union of 2 sub-queries. Ugh!

I believe there has to be a much better way to do this even without modifying the schema but I can't seem to find it. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

(Btw, I'm an embedded guy with no experience in databases, so forgive me if this is a dumb question or if there is a stupid simple solution which I've blatantly missed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the query below without testing, so there could be some errors.
Please replace 'ADDR' and 'RSSI' with their proper values (encoded) or use query parameters to avoid SQL injection.

```
INSERT INTO device_rssi(device_addr, room_id, rssi) 
    select * from (
      select 'ADDR', room_id, 'RSSI' from device_rssi where device_addr='ADDR' 
      union
      select 'ADDR', room_id, 'RSSI' from switches where device_id like 'ADDR____' 
      union
      select 'ADDR', room_id, 'RSSI' from sensors where device_id like 'ADDR____' 
    ) tmp limit 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE rssi = 'RSSI';
```

It is not ideal, especially because device_addr is not identical to device_id and because you can have the same device_id record in both sensors and switches.

Comment: Ah! Looks way better than my solution. Note that a device_id can either not exist in both switches and sensors or exist in only one of them. I'll give it a try and post an update! Thanks :-)

Comment: The large select with `union` is searching in all three tables and the `limit` clause will just take the first one. If the first record is the one that was found in device_rssi table, then the `on duplicate` part will kick in.

Comment: Like you said, if the 'addr' already exists in the device_rssi table, the 'on duplicate' part will kick in, so, do I really need the 'select' query for the device_addr table? Just the union of the 'select' on switches and sensors should get the job done, right?

Comment: If you don't include device_addr and there is no suitable data in switches and sensors, the union will return nothing. If nothing is returned, no insert is attempted and there is no reason for calling 'on duplicate'. I hope it makes sense. :)

Comment: If no device_id in switches or sensors matches the device_addr, then nothing should be inserted anyway! If a device doesn't exist in the DB, I wouldn't want to track its signal strength :-)

Comment: Then, I guess you can remove it.